# Why sometimes my instance of openmeetings server is runs from beginning

Tags: virtualbox, h2, openmeetings

I'd install and setup openmeetings instance on virualbox machine, it's goes pretty well. But sometimes after reboot when i'm trying to enter site it's redirecting to openmeetings/install page and says me to configure database, admin account etc.one again.
I am using virtualbox(and snapshots maybe it rolls back some parts of a disk somehow?), ubuntu server 16.04 lts.
Any ideas?

Comment: What DB are you using? Is it located at the same VM?

Comment: @MaximSolodovnik h2 at the same VM. all is configurated following guides https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html#local-installation https://openmeetings.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: @MaximSolodovnik i think problems are started when I tried to make a startup.sh script run after reboot.(through crontab, rc.local ways. I got the same result, after reboot the instance is redirect me to install page, but all the time)

Comment: h2 creates DB in the current folder, maybe some sort of clean-up is performed on reboot? It is not recommended to use H2 in production. I would use any other supported DB :)

Comment: @MaximSolodovnik omg, this is the problem :) if i run the script not from script's folder it's creating new database. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2 creates DB in the current folder,

maybe some sort of clean-up is performed on reboot?

It is not recommended to use H2 in production. I would use any other supported DB :)